# Less Verbose Way to Check Membership of Multiple Items in List/String?

Tags: python

I have code that checks if an attribute of a class as well as a predetermined string are in a string or a list, like this:

```
if (self.name in event and 'AL' in event) or (self.name in event and 'FH' in event)
```

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to combine these so I don't have to type out "in event" twice for both conditions. Obviously not a big deal, but I'm always in the market for making things a bit sexier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify an expression of the form `(x && y) || (x && z)` to the form `x && (y || z)`. Hence you can write your expression as:

```
if self.name in event and ('AL' in event or 'FH' in event):
    #...
```

Comment: You probably wanted `&&` there rather than `^` there, because, in the context of programming, `^` usually means "exclusive or", not "and". But otherwise, +1 for a good explanation.

Comment: Good point, for some reason it didn't even twig in my mind - was too busy thinking of it in propositional logic terms.

Comment: And yet you managed to explain it in novice-friendly terms without digressing to prove distribution of conjunction over disjunction from the axioms. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can factorise the `self.name in event` component out of the subexpressions, and use `any()` to iterate over the other names.

```
if self.name in event and any(it in event for it in ['AL', 'FH', ...]):
    ...
```

(Disclaimer: this is untested, so doublecheck if you get the same results as in your original.)